# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Requested table is not in this Realm

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-migration

I deleted one entry from `UserDatabse` in realm in `Activity "A"` and when I tested after deletion the size of `UserDatabase` it returns **"1"** , Then I started `Activity B` and then When the following Line executes :

```
 Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        final RealmResults<UserDatabase> stdList = realm.where(UserDatabase.class).findAll();
    Log.i("datatesthello","student databse size"+stdList.size());
```

**I get this error :java.lang.IllegalStateException:**

```
09-08 16:18:21.491 8517-9711/com.gurkhatech.hamroschool.guardian E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1712
 Process: com.gurkhatech.hamroschool.guardian, PID: 8517
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Requested table is not in this Realm. Creating it requires a transaction: class_UserDatabase                                                                                       
at io.realm.internal.Group.getTable(Group.java:193)
at io.realm.RealmSchema.getTable(RealmSchema.java:230)
at io.realm.RealmSchema.getSchemaForClass(RealmSchema.java:250)
at io.realm.RealmQuery.<init>(RealmQuery.java:139)
at io.realm.RealmQuery.createQuery(RealmQuery.java:88)
at io.realm.Realm.where(Realm.java:1050)
at com.gurkhatech.hamroschool.guardian.SplashActivity.validLogin(SplashActivity.java:81)
at com.gurkhatech.hamroschool.guardian.SplashActivity.access$000(SplashActivity.java:20)
at com.gurkhatech.hamroschool.guardian.SplashActivity$1.run(SplashActivity.java:37)
```

Also,.. the size of UserDatabase in activity B is "0" when I print it in Log.

Comment: Specify version of Realm

Comment: 1.2.0 is the version

Comment: Do you by chance use `android:process` in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: unfortunately no...

Comment: It sounds like some code somewhere is either deleting the Realm or you are setting the default database to something else.

Comment: I guess you should look for either something setting the value of `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration()` somewhere, or `Realm.deleteFile()`, or anything that resembles deleting the realm file while it's open

Comment: Yeah I do inside onCreate of Application 
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
        sInstance=this;

Comment: The question is more about deleting the Realm file.

Comment: Solution: Make sure you don't delete your open Realm file from some random place in your code

Comment: Is your project can always reproduce this? Can you share your project with us? To help@realm.io if you want to share it privately.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have deleted eth that comes in the data folder of app from a place  but funny thing is I get the lost entry in another activity again . Its getting even more stranger now

Comment: @beeender yeah sure why not .. I will have to share 4 java files for that  I think...

Comment: You're definitely deleting stuff in your `data` folder that you shouldn't be deleting.. for example your Realm file, lol